# Using tls certificate in http_client_config with casablanca (cpprestsdk)

Tags: c++, winapi, ssl, casablanca

I am stuck with creating a http_client which uses a tls certificate (with a private key) for authentication. The cert is available in the windows certificate store.

Using http_client_config::validate_certificates is not clear to me.

Sample:

```
http_client_config client_config;
client_config.set_validate_certificates(true);
... 

http_client client(U("https://url"), client_config);
```

The exception I get when trying to call the url is: "WinHttpSendRequest" 12044: A certificate is required

Can someone tell me to use a http_client with a tls cert?

Thank you.

Comment: you can use a `set_nativehandle_options` and inside a callback function, you can add a `WinHttpSetOption`